# Ubuntu Phonegap Error while creating app

Tags: node.js, cordova, ubuntu

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/util/connect-proxy.js:21
                fs.readFile(settings, (err, data) => {                                                ^SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/lib/phonegap/serve.js:9:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that the version of Node that you're sing doesn't support the arrow function syntax.

Which is strange because it must be 0.12 or older - which is not maintained any more and should be upgraded. The current version is 7.5.0, the latest LTS version is 6.9.5 (as of February 2017). Versions older than 4.x should not be used for anything.

For more info see:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

For Node versions compatibility with arrow function syntax see:

- http://node.green/#arrow-functions

For Node versions support schedule see:

- https://github.com/nodejs/LTS#lts-schedule